# Instant db field length validation on UI

Tags: database, validation, jsf, oracle9i

I am faced with an unusual problem in a project that I am developing. The requirements are not clear regarding the size of a dozen or so text area input fields on the web page and as a result of which, I find myself having to change not only the database column to increase length but also to change the size parameter specified in my JSF validator for that text area component. Since the code has changed, an emergency deployment is necessary which makes a lot of people mad. Unfortunately, no one is quite sure what length these data elements should be and we expect it to change often. I changed my varchars to clobs but unfortunately the clob sizes were also too small and had to be increased as well.
Are there any tools or APIs that will help me address this problem? Or any best practices? I am considering building a small, on demand feature that will generate all db column lengths and make it available to the application via a singleton class. The UI view would then reference that particular element thus eliminating the need for code deployment.

Does anyone have any better solutions?

I am using JSF1.2+EJB3+Weblogic+Oracle DB stack.

Thanks a lot for looking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem seems to be extreme case of a pretty normal use case.. (varchar to clob...:) )

You have not mentioned any ORM framework and I assume that you are not using Hibernate.

The first solution that comes to my mind is  Using [JSR 303](http://www.jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=303) . Its a very scalable, non intrusive validation framework. You can implement this framework in whichever tier you want to.  To hold the whole thing together, you could provide a single custom constraint [validator](http://people.redhat.com/~ebernard/validation/#constraintsdefinitionimplementation-validationimplementation-example) , that will internally have a way of loading max and min values based on the field.  The idea is to pass an parameter via annotation, indicating the field name, storing the min-max value of each field name in some external property file. So the validator, will dynamically load min max value based on the field name.

So you have a customized framework for validating each fields based on constraints stored in a property file. You could reuse the same constraint both in your presentation and also your DAO layer.

Of course, one things is unanswered.

1.How to propogate this change to the underlying database. You could provide maximum possible length in database and handle contraints in your application tier, but there might be performance consideration. (although,  I doubt there will be. Oracle is very very intelligent in its CBO).

Look here for a general [example](http://java.dzone.com/articles/bean-validation-and-jsr-303).

P.S: I have never tried this customization myself, but it is definitely possible.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you want to build validation code that reads database metadata at run time. The point is to avoid redeploying code.

The first part's not too hard. The second part's a little risky.

The maximum length of a column appears in at least some information_schema views.

```
select table_catalog, table_schema, table_name, 
       column_name, data_type, character_maximum_length
from information_schema.columns
where table_name = 'your-table-name'
order by table_catalog, table_schema, table_name, column_name
```

But some character data types might not have a value for character_maximum_length. PostgreSQL text columns, for example; columns of type 'text' have "unlimited" length.

Second, character_maximum_length doesn't take CHECK() constraints into account.

```
create table foo (
  bar varchar(50) check (length(bar) <= 35)
);
```

A control that read character_maximum_length from information_schema.columns would allow 50 characters, but the database wouldn't let you insert that many.

You might need to put some more administrative and QA processes in place to reduce the risk.

Comment: Thanks for the inputs. I use oracle 9 db and so i use the following query to generate table column lengths that i write to a file for use on the presentation tier for validation. `code` select table_name, column_name, data_length from all_tab_columns where table_name IN ( SELECT table_name FROM dba_tables t where owner=?1 ) and data_type IN ('VARCHAR2', 'CLOB') group by table_name, column_name, data_length order by table_name `code`

Comment: @Jaizen: ALL_TAB_COLUMNS.DATA_LENGTH does not list the maximum length for CLOBs.  Instead, the number represents the amount of space that may be used to store the data in the same row.  Usually this number is 4000.  The actual maximum size of a CLOB is at least several terabytes.